# App custom sticker not appearing in Gboard 10.6

Tags: android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing, gboard

On Latest Gboard 10.6 i am unable to see my app sticker where this is working with older version. What might be the core issue for why the stickers aren't showing up in Gboard on physical devices? Even though i tried with https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/app-indexing code this also not seeing on Gboard. Anyone help on same.

Answer (score 1):

Gboard apparently no longer supporting custom stickers via App Indexing and no path for continuity of functionality.  I really hope we get a suitable alternative some day.